# how to compare multiple files using jcl

Tags: sorting, cobol, mainframe, jcl, syncsort

I have a requirement where in I receive 6 files from upstream application into a GDG. I want to compare those all 6 version with one another to see any duplicates, i.e., it is a possibility that two or more files that came in may be duplicates (erroneously sent by upstream twice or multiple times). 
Could you please help on providing a solution using JCL or Cobol ?

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is to use the ISPF compare facility (ISPF 3.13 - SuperC or 3.13 - SuperCE) to compare the files but choose background execution rather than foreground. This will create a batch job which you can use as a template for steps to include in your job:

```
//SUPERC  EXEC PGM=ISRSUPC,PARM=(DELTAL,LINECMP,' SEQ','') 

//NEWDD   DD DISP=SHR,DSN=new.dataset 
//OLDDD   DD DISP=SHR,DSN=old.dataset   
//OUTDD   DD SYSOUT=*
```

Bear in mind that ISPF compare only compares 2 files; to compare 6 you'll need 15 steps (I think).

If your site has PDSMAN, then you can use its PDSM37 module to generate a checksum for each datasets and a small REXX to easily compare the 6 checksums.

Answer (score -1):

If they are properly strucured datasets (they are not files) then they should have header records. All you need do is compare the first record of each dataset. You could use your sort product or use ISRSUPC in batch.

JCL cannot do this as JCL only tells the operating system what programs and resources are needed to do the task. So even a COBOL solution would require JCL.

And, finally, I believe you are talking about generations no versions. Versions relate to the numbering after the GxxxxV.

Comment: There is nothing in z/OS that states every file needs a unique header record.

Comment: @Steve Ives: And I did not say, or imply, as such.

Comment: ok sorry. Can you explain what you meant by “they should have header records” and why comparing the first record of each file is a method to establish if two datasets are the same?

Comment: You can't use ISRSUPC to compare just the first record and even if you could, it would not tell you if the files are the same. The first records could be the same but the rest of the files could be different.

Comment: True you could not use SUPERC but with DFSort you can (joinkeys) and if the headers were there and they were identical then it would indicate that the two datasets contained the same data. depends of course on what data you include in the header record e.g. date and time and a run sequence.

Comment: Again you are promoting this idea that z/OS datasets have headers that tell you if 2 files are the same - something you denied a few comments back. Where are you getting this from? It's completely wrong and if you proceed on that assumption, you'll get a lot of errors. DF/SORT JOINKEYS is for merging datasets, not comparing.

Comment: I am not saying all z/os datasets have headers. I am saying that a well designed application will have headers (and trailers) in which case, if a dataset is sent twice a comparison of the headers could indicate this situation. And JOINKEYS can compare records and one would, first of all, use MERGE to merge datasets.